# Running SqlQuery to count rows by date

Tags: entity-framework-5

I'm not good with Entity Framework yet so planned to run raw query. Now I'm stuck with this. When using the following code, I get the following error.

> Error CS1061  'Respons' does not contain a definition for 'TotalCount' and
>   no extension method 'Total' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Respons' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

When I run the same query in SSMS, I get the follow result.

[image]

***Respons.cs***

```
namespace Survey.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Respons
    {
        public int ResponseID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

***Raw Query***

```
DbSqlQuery<Respons> Responses = DbContext.Responses.SqlQuery("SELECT max(ResponseID) AS ResponseID, COUNT(CreatedDateTime) AS Total, MAX(FORMAT(CreatedDateTime, 'dd-MMM-yyyy', 'en-US' )) as Date FROM Responses GROUP BY CAST(CreatedDateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY Date DESC");
foreach ( var r in Responses ){
   Response.Write( r.TotalCount);
}
```

Comment: The error is crystal clear: your class `Respons` doesn't contain a property `TotalCount` - so even if your SQL might *return* that value, there's no property around to actually store it. So when you go iterate over all the data returned - how do you imagine the total count could be shown, if your class `Respons` doesn't contain any property for it?!?!?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a `ViewModel` class as follows:

```
public class TotalCountByDateViewModel
{
   public int TotalCount { get; set; }
   public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

Now write your query as follows:

```
DbSqlQuery<TotalCountByDateViewModel> totalCountsByDate = DbContext.Responses
  .SqlQuery("SELECT max(ResponseID) AS ResponseID, COUNT(CreatedDateTime)
  AS Total, MAX(FORMAT(CreatedDateTime, 'dd-MMM-yyyy', 'en-US' ))
  as Date FROM Responses GROUP BY CAST(CreatedDateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY Date DESC");
```

Answer (score 1):

well, it is very clear from message that your class is missing "Total count" property.

How to write group by query refer to this link:

[LINQ GroupBy translation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation)